# What happened to Optimus Prime's trailer when he transformed into a robot?

Tags: transformers

When (the original, G1) Optimus Prime transformed into robot mode, this trailer just seemed to disappear. When he went back into truck mode, there was his trailer again!

I'm guessing this was to help the animation and story telling. But what was the **in-universe** explanation? Where did it go?

This question is applicable to both the comic and the cartoon continuities.

Comment: just guessing, but maybe the trailer was holographic?

Comment: @Xantec It cannot because of the [Roller](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Roller_%28G1%29) which is stored within the trailer and that is not an hologram for sure.

Comment: Has anyone considered the possibility that Optimus has dozens, possibly hundreds of identical trailers hidden around the American Northwest, and he just calls in the closest one whenever he transforms?

Comment: The trailer opens up into a gun turret which fires small plastic missiles at Optimus Prime's enemies! Or at least, mine does...

Comment: After separation, the trailer dematerialises and holds position in the Time Vortex until Prime sends a signal and calls it out again. This results from a previous encounter betweeen Prime and the Doctor in a story that I've literally just made up.

Comment: @maguirenumber6: that could happen. After all, [The Doctor met Death's Head](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uM1cLUdCqgI/ThXi19RbcHI/AAAAAAAAAfs/EXK6vcNoJJk/s1600/Blog-03-3-Crossroads-of-Time.jpg) who has featured in multiple Transformer stories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now an official answer, the:

## Subspace Storage Pocket

[Greg Sepelak](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Greg_Sepelak) and [Trent Troop](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Trent_Troop) used this phrase in two of their stories for the official [Transformers Collectors' Club](http://www.transformersclub.com/) comic. Hence this phrase is now canon.

The **subspace storage pocket** is used by multiple transformers, eg for weapons storage, gestalt parts and [mass changes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8527/143).

Source; [this rather awesome video](https://youtu.be/sXn1p3lIrNg)<sup>1</sup>:

<sub>1 The whole [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEOvklHZd3m5qNxtMis4zRQ) is great.</sub>

Answer (score 23):

There is no in universe explanation form the cartoon continuities. For the comics, it look like there is one.

Form the [Transformers Wiki, Note section of the Trailer article](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Trailer)

> When Optimus Prime transforms into robot mode, his trailer usually disappears, only to reattach itself to Prime whenever he goes into vehicle mode. Many **fan theories** about this disappearance have arisen over the years, with the most popular being that **Prime stores the trailer in subspace.** IDW comics gives a nod to this, by having **the trailer arrive at Prime's location using the orbital jump**.

Comment: Whenever "The Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe" dealt with unexplained mass shifting, it always referred to "an unknown, possibly extradimensional source." I find this to be a useful "explanation" when dealing with Transformers G1 cartoons as well.

Comment: Makes me think of [Ultraviolet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0370032/)

Comment: I always thought it was just some sort of holographic projection, but with mass (like the Star Trek holodecks).

Answer (score 11):

The General consensus is that it just goes over there, i.e. just out of camera shot. Funnily this is subverted in the original Marvel Comics four issue run, where Prime's trailer just sits there clearly visible not doing anything while the action takes place around it.

The second bullet point on [this tfwiki page](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Power_Play!#Continuity_notes) says:

> During the entire battle at the Witwicky's house, Optimus Prime's trailer sits parked, frequently in view. This is in stark contrast to the more fantastical cartoon, where it would just roll off-screen and vanish.

Answer (score 2):

Another theory produced by a Transformers fan is that the trailer is **created each time by the creation matrix**.

To quote from the end of the [video](http://youtu.be/2v1SBX5S2rU):

> I think the matrix gives Optimus Prime and Rodimus Prime the ability to manifest a trailer whenever they transform into a truck.

Personally I'm not convinced that the creation matrix has the ability to manifest real world objects; I think its purpose is to *impart life* to Transformers. But I like the theory and the fact that the fan has, rightly, also taken Rodimus Prime into account.

Comment: I'm unsure if this should be an answer or a comment. Thoughts?

Comment: Kind of borderline quality since it doesn't spell out any evidence, but it's an answer. The Autobot's melancholy when they think Roller has been destroyed in one episode leads me to believe that he's not being detroyed/re-created, though.

Comment: @phantom42: thanks, my thoughts exactly.

Comment: This answer is the only one with evidence. In the cartoon, it materializes from somewhere, full stop.

Answer (score 2):

### Optimus Prime has people to take care of these things

Here we see his loyal subordinate *Huffer* towing his trailer:

[image]

Comment: *Huffer* also comes into play in the G1 Transformers UK comic #39, 'Prime Time', but I can't find a picture of that.

Answer (score 1):

Theory 1: inside every transformer is the ability to shrink--but not enlarge--themselves and any of their components in robot or disguise mode (This would also explain why Sky Fire and Astro Train can fit groups of transformers who shouldn't fit inside them--and why Megatron and Sound Wave transform into things much smaller than their robot modes.).

Theory 2: Optimus stores his trailer in another dimension and can bring it to this dimension at will--either because any transformer can or because the matrix allows him.

Theory 3: like the Allspark in the first Michael Bay film, Transformers can fold themselves and different components over into very small objects; in Optimus's case, he would store the condensed trailer in his body.

Theory 4: like Mirage, Optimus's trailer can turn invisible and follows Optimus around everywhere while he's in robot mode.